# determine the kernel of this function, find a basis for the kernel and the dual space?

Tags: linear-algebra

So i was having trouble with this and would really, really appreciate if people could help me out because i'm getting stressed out about it.

here's the question:

so let $P_3$ denote the vector space of real polynomials of order three or less in a single variable x. Consider the map $F:P_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$F(p(x)) = $$\int_{0}^{1} p(x) dx$

I have already had to show that $F$ is a linear map and that part was fine it's just the next bits I don't get.

...a)  W.R.T to the basis $({1,x,x^2,x^3})$ for $P_3$  and the basis $(1)$ for $\mathbb{R}$, write down the matrix which represents $F$.

...b) Hence or otherwise determine the kernel of $F$, and write down a basis.

...c) Define three other functions  $G_1, G_2, G_3$ which together with $F$ form a basis for the dual space $P_3^*$.  briefly justify your answer.

I was thinking a) would be something like

\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 \end{array}

but this is as much as I can get out.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here are some hints/direction:

a) Remember, the matrix representation of $F$ will be used to left multiply a coordinate vector of $p \in P_3$ (such a vector has 4 components), and the result of this multiplication will then be a real number (1 component). What does that tell you about the matrix order (rows and columns) of $F$? So we have Mtx$_{\epsilon,\alpha}(F)[p]_\alpha=[F(p)]_\epsilon=F(p) \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\epsilon$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha$ the standard basis for $P_3$.

b) Here you just have to solve the homogenous system Mtx$_{\epsilon,\alpha}(F)[p]_\alpha=0$

c) This one is harder. But basically, if we take $B=\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ with $a_i$ distinct positive real numbers not equal to $1$ and we let $G_i=\int_{0}^{a_i} p(x) dx$, then we want to prove that \begin{equation}\sum_{i=1}^3 b_iG_i+b_4F=0 \end{equation} implies $b_i=0$ for all $i$. The resulting coefficient matrix for the system above is a Vandermonde matrix (you can check this), which is invertible, and hence has only the trivial solution.